# Hdparm does not apply spindown settings

Tags: debian, hard-disk, hdparm

I have conf for hdparm:
/etc/hdparm.conf

```
apm = 127
force_spindown_time = 120
/dev/sda {
 apm = 127
 acoustic_management = 128
 spindown_time = 120
 }
/dev/sdb {
 apm = 127
 acoustic_management = 128
 spindown_time = 120
 }
```

But **hdparm -S** show missing value

```
root@DietPi:~# hdparm -S /dev/[sh]d[a-z]
  -S: bad/missing standby-interval value (0..255)
```

If I run command to enable it - everything seems ok, but no. Settings does not apply:

```
root@DietPi:~# hdparm -S 120 /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 setting standby to 120 (10 minutes)
root@DietPi:~# hdparm -S /dev/sda
  -S: bad/missing standby-interval value (0..255)
root@DietPi:~# hdparm -B /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 APM_level      = 127
root@DietPi:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

`hdparm -S` requires a value provided to set the timeout. It will not work without that value, unlike `-B`, for example.

From hdparm:

```
-S   Set standby (spindown) timeout
```

There is no `Get`. It is not possible to see the previously set value with hdparm.

That your disk does not spin down is an entirely different problem. There is a lot of information on the internet to identify possible causes, which I will not list in this brief answer.