# hdparm suspend disk : SG_IO: bad/missing sense data

Tags: hard-disk, gentoo, hdparm

I'm trying to suspend two 8TB drives that are set up as RAID1 with logical volumes on them.

The disks are identical so I show output for only one here but have the same output (bar `Unique ID`) for both `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd`.

```
hdparm -I /dev/sd{c,d}

/dev/sdc:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST8000VN004-2M2101
    Serial Number:      WSD600F2
    Firmware Revision:  SC60
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0xffff)
    Supported: 11 10 9 8 7 6 5
    Likely used: 11
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors: 15628053168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes [ Supported: 512 4096 ]
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     7630885 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     8001563 MBytes (8001 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 3.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Recommended acoustic management value: 254, current value: 0
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    Media Card Pass-Through
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    unknown 119[6]
       *    unknown 119[7]
            unknown 119[8]
            unknown 119[9]
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
            unknown 78[7]
            unknown 78[11]
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[7]
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
            unknown 206[14] (vendor specific)
       *    SANITIZE_ANTIFREEZE_LOCK_EXT command
       *    SANITIZE feature set
       *    OVERWRITE_EXT command
       *    Extended number of user addressable sectors
Security:
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    710min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 710min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c500e3a7bf51
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000c50
    Unique ID   : 0e3a7bf51
Checksum: correct
```

My reading of the above is that I can the drive...

- Supports Power Management (APM).
- Has a password but its not enabled, nor is the drive locked or frozen and the security count has not expired.

And so I have tried setting spin-down with both `hdparm -B` and `hdparm -S`.

### `hdparm -B`

```
# hdparm -B /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 APM_level  = not supported
```

Surprising given info says it supports `Power Management feature set` or is it `Device-initiated interface power management` that is relevant here and isn't supported by this drive?

```
 # hdparm -B 127 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x7f (127)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 7f 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 APM_level  = not supported
```

Found a [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1213715/hdparm-error-sg-io-bad-missing-sense-data) suggesting the `SG_IO: bad/missing sense data` error can be remedied by suspending but not dice here.

### `hdparm -S`

```
# hdparm -S 127 /dev/sd{c,d}

/dev/sdc:
 setting standby to 127 (10 minutes + 35 seconds)
```

Looks promising but on checking...

```
# hdparm -S  /dev/sd{c,d}
  -S: bad/missing standby-interval value (0..255)
```

Its not retained. Related [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715598/hdparm-does-not-apply-spindown-settings).

### Questions

Given the above...

1. How to resolve the `SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]`?
2. How to correctly suspend the disks on idle?

Main reason for wanting to do this is two fold, firstly the drives are quite noisy and secondly they don't actually get used regularly as the hold music/work that only gets used periodically.